# JAVA Android: Logging in... (freezes)

Tags: java, android, freeze

I have no clue why the app freezes while it tries to connect to a TCP server. It does establish a connection I know that, because it signs me off the other messenger when I connect to it, but it just freezes as it says "Logging in.."

```
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: error upgrading the database to version 309
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4509)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4281)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4237)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: error upgrading the database to version 309
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsDatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(ContactsDatabaseHelper.java:1507)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:108)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(ContactsDatabaseHelper.java:2507)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider.onCreate(CallLogProvider.java:79)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:733)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4506)
07-01 05:37:55.297: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  ... 12 more
07-01 05:37:55.328: W/ActivityManager(59): Process android.process.acore has crashed too many times: killing!
07-01 05:37:55.328: W/ActivityManager(59): Unable to launch app com.android.providers.contacts/10009 for provider call_log: launching app became null
07-01 05:37:55.328: E/ActivityThread(114): Failed to find provider info for call_log
```

I have looked at these logs trying to figure out the problem but nothing has worked out on my favor yet... what is causing the app being frozen?

EDIT:

```
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.Socket;

 public class Connectionn extends Thread implements XfireObserver {
    private DataInputStream in = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private String username, password, nickname, statustext = "Online";
    private boolean runThread = true;

    public Connectionn() {
            EventManager.addObserver(this);
    }

    /**
     * Connect to Xfire using the username and password provided in the constructor.
     */
    public void connect(String username, String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            try {
                    if (!runThread)
                            return;
                    Socket s = new Socket("cs.xfire.com", 25999);
                    in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    login();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    disconnect();
            }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
            EventManager.removeObserver(this);
            runThread = false;

            try {
                    out.write(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }); // sabotage the stream                    
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    try {
                            out.close();
                            in.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FriendManager.getInstance().cleanup();
                    EventManager.fireEvent(new DatalessEvent(XfireEvent.XF_OFFLINE));
            }
    }

    public void run() {
            setName("Xfire Reader Thread");

            while(runThread) {
                    readBytes();
                    debug(buffer);

                    switch(buffer[0] & 0xFF) {
                    case 0x80: // salt
                            SaltPacket sp = new SaltPacket(buffer);
                            LoginPacket lp = new LoginPacket(username, password, sp.getSalt());
                            write(lp.getBytes());
                            break;
                    case 0x81: // auth failed
                            disconnect();
                            EventManager.fireEvent(new DatalessEvent(XfireEvent.XF_LOGINFAIL));
                            break;
                    case 0x82: // loginreply
                            LoginReplyPacket lrp = new LoginReplyPacket(buffer);
                            nickname = lrp.getNickname();
                            break;
                    case 0x83: // friendslist
                            new FriendslistPacket(buffer);
                            break;
                    case 0x84: // friend online
                            new FriendStatusPacket(buffer);
                            break;
                    case 0x85: // receive message
                            ReceiveMessagePacket rmp = new ReceiveMessagePacket(buffer);
                            if (rmp.getMessageType() == ReceiveMessagePacket.MSGTYPE_IM) {
                                    AckImPacket amp =
                                            new AckImPacket(rmp.getSid(), rmp.getImIndex());
                                    write(amp.getBytes());
                            }
                            break;
                    case 0x87: // friend in game
                            new FriendGamePacket(buffer);
                            break;
                    case 0x91: // disconnected with reason
                            disconnect();
                            EventManager.fireEvent(new DatalessEvent(XfireEvent.XF_DCREASON));
                            break;
                    case 0x9a: // friend status text
                            new FriendStatusTextPacket(buffer);
                            break;
                    case 0xac:
                            new ScreenshotsPacket(buffer);
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }

    private void login() {
            // initialize connection with the 'UA01' packet
            write("UA01".getBytes());

            System.out.println("asd");

            // send the version packet
            VersionPacket vp = new VersionPacket();
            write(vp.getBytes());

            // start the reader thread
            try{
            start();
            }catch(Exception threade){
                System.out.println("Thread was not called!");
            }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the nickname set for this Xfire user.
     * @return the current nickname.
     */
    public String getNickname() {
            return nickname;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new nickname for this Xfire user.
     * @param nick the nickname to set.
     */
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
            ChangeNickPacket cnp = new ChangeNickPacket(nickname);
            write(cnp.getBytes());
            this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getStatusText() {
            return statustext;
    }

    public void setStatusText(String statustext) {
            ChangeStatusTextPacket cstp = new ChangeStatusTextPacket(statustext);
            write(cstp.getBytes());
            this.statustext = statustext;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
            return username;
    }

    public void handleEvent(XfireEvent event) {
            switch(event.getEventType()) {
            case XfireEvent.XF_SENDIM:
                    SendImEvent e = (SendImEvent)event;
                    SendImPacket sip = new SendImPacket(e.getSid(), e.getImindex(),
                                    e.getMessage());
                    write(sip.getBytes());
                    return;
            case XfireEvent.XF_REQINFO:
                    Friend f = ((FriendEvent)event).getFriend();
                    RequestInfoPacket rip = new RequestInfoPacket(f.getUserid());
                    write(rip.getBytes());
                    return;
            }
    }

    /*
     * I/O and debugging methods
     */
    private void readBytes() {
            try {
                    byte[] numBytes = new byte[2];
                    in.read(numBytes, 0, 2);
                    int low = numBytes[0] & 0xFF, high = numBytes[1] & 0xFF;
                    int len = (0x00 | low | (high << 8)) - 2;

                    if (len <= 0) {
                            buffer = new byte[] { 0 };
                            return;
                    }

                    buffer = new byte[len];
                    in.read(buffer, 0, len);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    disconnect();
            }
    }

    public void write(byte[] bs) {
            try {
                    out.write(bs);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    disconnect();
            }
    }

    private static void debug(byte[] bs) {
            for (byte b : bs) {
                    System.out.print(String.format("%02x", b) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thats the point.. i dont know where exactly it casues the crash.. there are 40 classes in this app, but I THINK it could be because of this class, please read the question again, i will update it soon

Comment: Okay ive updated it.. could there be a problem in the thread?

Comment: Just try and debug your application in sequence of how the code actually executes to pin point where your application is actually getting frozen!

Comment: After some more time into the debug, I still couldn't figure it out. This is really mind bugging :/ . Is it possible if you could check it for me yourself? I.E. Teamviewer ..

Comment: I get a similar error when I try to open the camera activity. It could be the OS shutting down your initial activity to save resources, but I'm not 100% sure.